# How to fix connection timeout error in android studio 3?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I update my android studio to version 3 and when i create a new project , I receive this error

> connection timeout error !

How can i fix this error ?

Comment: Stack Overflow already contains various questions on this error message for older versions. Have you tried searching and applying any of the answers?  e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667711/android-studio-error-errorconnection-timed-out

Comment: Yes i tried already . but i don,t get true result