# Failed to resolve: com.afollestad.material-dialogs: core:0.8.5.2

Tags: android, gradle

I, m using Android Studio 2.1.2, and in my project I hava a problem with com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.2, when I add com.afollestad.material-dialogs to my Gradle, error was show: Failed to resolve: com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.2,

**Here is my Gradle:**

```
buildscript {
 repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

**And this is my Gradle: app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
 configurations.all {
   resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
}
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.panaceasoft.mokets"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.5'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:2.0.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'
compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.1.4'

compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.2@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.3'}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And this is my SDK manager:
[image: sdk manager]

[image: sdk manager]

[image: sdk manager]

[image: sdk manager]

when I remove

```
compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.2@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

everything is fine and gradle build finished with no errors,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the latest version instead of aar.

```
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
```

**NOTE**

You should upgrade your versions

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
```

Then

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
```

Then

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

**Finally**

```
repositories {
        jcenter()
       // google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
```

Comment: how to upgrade my Gradle?

Comment: @NaserRajaei `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'`

Comment: now i'm using gradle:2.1.2, upgrade to gradle:3.1.2 or not?

Comment: i use VPN and i have this error : `Error:Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.`

Comment: @NaserRajaei https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3636 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667711/android-studio-error-errorconnection-timed-out

Comment: @NaserRajaei Solved this yet?

Comment: update my android studio to 3.1.2 and my gradle update to 3.1.2, now i'm a problem with `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'` with this error `Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0.`

Comment: @NaserRajaei `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'`

Comment: same error `Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0.`

Comment: @NaserRajaei click on error link and do gradle online

Comment: when i click to error link https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/3.2.0/google-services-3.2.0.pom, the browser not showing or downloading the file, and get this error : `404. That’s an error.`

Comment: i don'n understand what i do, please explain more

Comment: @NaserRajaei `File--->Sync project with gradle files`

Comment: i forgot to add jcenter(), it solved... now i have a error with all dependencies, `Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1`

Comment: add `jcenter(),google(),maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}` and i have this error `Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1.
`

Comment: remove `google()` and i have same error... `Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1.`

Comment: @NaserRajaei https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999594/unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdebug-compileclasspath-could-not-resolv

Answer (score 0):

try with the latest version of the library

```
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
```

Comment: when i use `compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'` i have this error : 

Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1
Install Repository and sync project
Open File
Show in Project Structure dialog