# Android Studio 3.2.1 Project sync failed

Tags: android, gradle, synchronization

I am a beginner  Android Programmer.
i have android project source but can not run and have error Sync failed.
my android studio version is 3.2.1 
sdk version from api 19 to api 26
gradle version 3.2.1 to 5.1 download from gradle website

Error when sync project

[image: image :Error when sync project]

Gradle Setting

[image: image : Gradle Setting]

Gradle-wrapper-properties

[image: image :Gradle-wrapper-properties]

gradle setting

[image: image : gradle setting]

i tested offline mode and  in setting use local gradle distribution but can not sync project

Run button

[image: image : Run button]

### and run button disable !!!

After set Proxy to android studio and download some file

```
Cannot create variant 'android-manifest-metadata' after configuration ':app:debugApiElements' has been resolved
```

Comment: I think it's a network issue, please resync it again

Comment: in Gradle-wrapper-properties file i changed Gradle version to 3.2.1  but  i have error Sync Failed and Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'ContactsMapAndroid' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 3.2.1 and sync project</li><li>The project 'ContactsMapAndroid' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file</li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin</li>

Comment: Tanks Basi
But Im Trying from yesterday

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android studio error Error:Connection timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667711/android-studio-error-errorconnection-timed-out)

Comment: Hi , I Setup Proxy Setting Android studio by https://github.com/freedomofdevelopers/fod  And After Download Some Files I give Error  " Could not find gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.jar "

Answer (score 0):

make sure u have high speed internet connection , in sudan we have another problem that is some sites are blocked from us we use vpn applications before we can synchronizing the project ,to check that try to rich developer.android.com from browser

Comment: Tanks fox for answering
I dont think its speeding up the internet
Gradle sync failed: Could not find gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1).
Searched in the following locations:   https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.jarConsult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (499 ms)