How to Automate Adding Dependencies for an Android Plugin in Unity?
I've created an Android plugin for Unity, and it requires some dependencies to be added manually. The current steps to do this are:

Go to Edit > Project Settings > Player > Publishing Settings.
Enable "Custom Main Gradle Template."
Navigate to and open the mainTemplate.gradle file.
Add the dependencies I provided.

Is there a way to automate this process?
I was considering:

A pre-build script that adds the dependencies.

using System.IO;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Build;
using UnityEditor.Build.Reporting;
using UnityEngine;

public class GradleTemplateModifier : IPreprocessBuildWithReport
{
    public int callbackOrder => 0;

    public void OnPreprocessBuild(BuildReport report)
    {
        if (report.summary.platform == BuildTarget.Android)
        {
            string gradleTemplatePath = "Assets/Plugins/Android/mainTemplate.gradle";
            if (File.Exists(gradleTemplatePath))
            {
                string content = File.ReadAllText(gradleTemplatePath);
                string[] dependencies = new[]
                {
                    "implementation 'com.example:some-dependency:1.0.0'",
                };

                foreach (var dependency in dependencies)
                {
                    if (!content.Contains(dependency))
                    {
                        int index = content.LastIndexOf("dependencies {") + "dependencies {".Length;
                        content = content.Insert(index, $"\n\t{dependency}");
                        File.WriteAllText(gradleTemplatePath, content);
                        Debug.Log("Added dependency to mainTemplate.gradle");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

In this script, I'm adding the plugin dependencies directly to the `mainTemplate.gradle` file and saving it. However, this approach has some issues:

If I need to update the dependency version, I also need to remove the old one.

If the user is using an old dependency version, it could create conflicts.


As you can see, I need help with the overall flow and implementation. I'm sure there's a much better solution out there.
From what i read unity doesn't support multiple build.gradle files.
Is there an easier why? Is there a built in why?

This makes no sense: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/gradle-templates.html

.gradle files are in Groovy, so you could use a Groovy parser. For example, Groovy has a built-in parser: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.3.0/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/tools/shell/Parser.html
I don't see a well-supported way to call Groovy code from C#, but you could stick all the dependencies in a directory (to make the solution portable) and have C# use a command line/shell to invoke the script.

Also, gradle is typical Java stuff. I know IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio has a semi-automatic way of doing this.

For a less Unity-specific conversation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538824/how-to-update-gradle-dependencies-to-their-latest-version
